Moving User pk to another field
Django derives the session key from the primary key in the User model:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/_modules/django/contrib/auth/
request.session[SESSION_KEY] = user._meta.pk.value_to_string(user)

We can also see that Django takes the session key and casts it to the primary keys type using:
get_user_model()._meta.pk.to_python(request.session[SESSION_KEY])

I want to change the session key from the user's name to the id I am using in my backend.
However, if I change the primary key on my user model, I will break active sessions that are using the user name as the session key.
How might I change the user field without breaking active sessions?

If the username can change, using it as a primary key is not a good idea: the ORM to some extent reasons that the primary key does not change, so defining an object in memory with the same pk will update the record, saving the record with a different username will "duplicate" it with a new record.

Normally it will use .get_user(user_id) from the backend, unless you use some sort of caching framework in which case it will use the ._cached_user of the request. It will use the backend specified in the session data under the _auth_user_backend key.

"change the session key from the user's name" but the session key is not the user's name to begin with? By default the primary key field for the user model is an AutoField and not their username which just has a unique constraint.

@Abdul Aziz Barkat In my model it is currently the username field but I want to change it.

Uhh, technically the session key is read in a middleware and that's what adds the user attribute to the request object. You could add your own middleware to interplay with this but its going to be a messy thing.

@willeM_ Van Onsem The username can't change, but either way I don't want to use the username field as the primary key  anymore but instead the unique user uuid I use in the backend.

How does Django finds the user for a given session
The details are, as probably in most web frameworks, a bit messy, and requires some digging. The request.user is set in the AuthenticationMiddleware [Django-doc] with a SimpleLazyObject [GitHub]:

class AuthenticationMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if not hasattr(request, "session"):
            raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                "The Django authentication middleware requires session "
                "middleware to be installed. Edit your MIDDLEWARE setting to "
                "insert "
                "'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware' before "
                "'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware'."
            )
        request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request))
        request.auser = partial(auser, request)


The get_user(…) [GitHub] itself does not much more than checking if the user is somehow already cached, and if not fetch it:

def get_user(request):
    if not hasattr(request, "_cached_user"):
        request._cached_user = auth.get_user(request)
    return request._cached_user


Now the interesting part is the auth.get_user(…) [GitHub], which looks if the session data contains the user session key, and the backend to use:

def get_user(request):
    # …
    user_id = _get_user_session_key(request)
    backend_path = request.session[BACKEND_SESSION_KEY]
    # …

It is thus important to note that the session does not only keep the user_id, but also the backend that was used for that id, to prevent having to enumerate over the backends again.
But even if that was not the case, it is not easy to just change the backend. Indeed, if we look at _get_user_session_key(…) [GitHub], we see:

def _get_user_session_key(request):
    # This value in the session is always serialized to a string, so we need
    # to convert it back to Python whenever we access it.
    return get_user_model()._meta.pk.to_python(request.session[SESSION_KEY])


It thus uses the primary key field to "deserialize" the session key, even if you would have used a different field first.
This is the same when we log in: in the login(…) function [GitHub], it sets the primary key of the user:

def login(request, user, backend=None):
    # …
    request.session[SESSION_KEY] = user._meta.pk.value_to_string(user)
    # …

The two are thus much tailored towards the primary key. The (default) ModelBackend, does not do much, except fetching the item with the primary key [GitHub]:

def get_user(self, user_id):
    try:
        user = UserModel._default_manager.get(pk=user_id)
    except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
        return None
    return user if self.user_can_authenticate(user) else None


Work (temporary) with two primary keys

However, if I change the primary key on my user model to the id field, I will break active sessions that are using the user name as the session key.

You coud monkey-patch the .get_user(…) method of the ModelBackend, for example in the .ready() method [Django-doc] of any of the AppConfigs in your project:
# app_name/apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig


class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    def ready(self):
        from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

        UserModel = get_user_model()

        def get_user(self, user_id):
            try:
                user = UserModel._default_manager.get(pk=user_id)
            except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
                try:
                    user = UserModel._default_manager.get(username=user_id)
                except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
                    return None
            return user if self.user_can_authenticate(user) else None

        from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend

        ModelBackend.get_user = get_user  # 🖘 monkey-patch
But that being said, I don't think that people getting logged out is that much of a big deal: eventually people will get logged out, because the cookie expires holding the session, or because of other reasons.
I think that using two natural keys imposes a security risk: if I somehow know the UUID of a certain user, I could try to rename the username to that UUID, essentially stealing the session.
Conclusion
What is perhaps more important is that the primary key of a model should typically be seen as a blackbox item. Sure, the primary key of many models is in fact an integer, but that is a technical detail. It makes not much sense to add two primary keys together for example. In database design, typically they teach to make the primary key a natural key. It is more a "Django-ism" to always use a black-box object, such as an AutoField, or a UUIDField.
While one can use monkey patch, it only introduces security risks, so I would advise not to do that, and let the sessions just expire: people then can login again. Changing the primary key imposes also the same risks.

thanks for your reply @willeM_ Van Onsem. I think login will also throw if I change the primary key because it will fail to serialise an older session key.

@Baz: it will, you should add in the migration file where the primary key is changed something that throws out session data.

@Baz: or if you really want to retain sessions, make a small piece of middleware in front of the authentication one, that "translates" the session keys to the new ones. But I don't think that is a good idea.

@Baz: the other option is to monkey-patch the items that raise an error, and thus for example try to deserialize with the .pk first and if that does not work with the .username, but again, I think this is a security vulnerability.[

and again your fear would be someone changing their username to a uuid? I already have a custom auth backend so its in the session as BACKEND_SESSION_KEY. If I add a new backend for the new sessions (now using a different pk field), I would know if a session is new or old. In this pre authentication middleware, if I see an old session, I get the uuid for that username from the backend and write it in to the session as the updated session key. I can then delete that middleware after the old sessions have all expired. Or do you see an issue with that in terms of security?

my last comment is with respect to your suggestion regarding pre authentication middleware.

@Baz: not per se changing, just registering might also work. I think it always is a security vulnerability if people have control over the primary key, since that means they can start linking, and thus "hijack" "references".

@Baz: as for the expiring, the question is how you know that all the old ones are expired. A small amount of middleware that migrations the SESSION_KEYs and that is put before the AuthenticationMiddleware could work, but this still has some potential security flaws.

If I add a middleware prior to AuthenticationMiddleware, can I  log out the user by calling request.session.flush() after confirming that this is an old session type? I'll go with this approach if it doesn't have security issues.

@Baz if you're using the database backend for sessions you can invalidate all of them as part of a migration or a management command. If you want to be extra sure you can override get_session_auth_hash and change the salt being used so the older session hashes become invalid. IMO invalidating old sessions is much easier than trying to support both old and new.
